# Get value from resultset in an array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-8.4

I am using postgresql. I am executing a query with some rows

```
queryObj = session.createSQLQuery(query);
```

I have an object say **`Object[ ] row = null;`**

The query gives me a table consisting of 5 columns and 10 rows.

How to use the row object to get the individual row data?
In my case the total number of data is **5*10=50**

How do i iterate so that i can go through /save individual element of the table in my row object?

Edit:

I am using(sadly need to adhere to this ) some syntax like :

```
Object[] row = null;
for( i=0 ;i< resultList.size(); i++){
row = (Object[])resultList.get(i); ....
```

In this case how do you suggest i should get the values in a string or string array ..?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is a SELECT, iterating through the result set is simple.

```
queryObj = session.createSQLQuery(query);
List<Object> rows = queryObj.executeQuery();

//This will x amount of times, where x is the amount of rows returned.
for(Object row : rows){
   String colA = row[0];
   String colB = row[1];
   String colC = row[2];
   String colD = row[3];
   String colE = row[4];
}
```

If your table represents an entity, you should create a POJO representing it, then it would be simpler - all you would need to do is cast the object to your concrete type.